# Operator for scaling a function?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, notation, terminology, operator-theory

Let $\mathbb{F}$ denote the set of functions of the form $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.

I am interested to know whether there exists a well-known linear map $T_\alpha: \mathbb{F} \to \mathbb{F}$ such that $Tf(x) = f(\alpha x)$.

What would be the formal name of such an operator?

Comment: Does the the set of functions have any special property?

Comment: Not really, we can assume continuity over the entire real line.

Comment: Composition operator.

Comment: @T.A.E. the composition operator is incorrect as it does not achieve the task at hand. Perhaps I was ambiguous, but $\alpha$ is a constant real number.

Comment: You can call it a scaling operator if you want. But it is also a composition $f\circ\varphi$ where $\varphi(x)=\alpha x$.

Comment: $a^{x \partial_x}f(x)=f(ax)$
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1341495/exponential-of-powers-of-the-derivative-operator

Answer (score 0):

It is called the ***dilatation operator***, and it is but a coordinate change of the [Lagrange shift operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_operator).    Define 
$$
x\equiv e^y , \qquad \alpha \equiv e^\beta,
$$
so that 
$$
T f(e^y)= f(e^{y+\beta}).
$$
That is, *T* is a shifter,
$$
T= e^{\beta \frac{d}{dy}}=e^{\ln\! \alpha ~~~x\frac{d}{dx}},
$$
so that 
$$
T f(x) = f(\alpha x).
$$