# Which functions $f$ satisfies the equation $f’(x)=\dfrac{1}{x}\left(f(\sqrt{1-x^2})- f(x)\right)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, recreational-mathematics, functional-equations

What functions $f$ satisfy the equation 
$$f'(x)=\frac{f(\sqrt{1-x^2})  -  f(x)}x$$

Could you kindly show how you arrived at the function?

Comment: Thanks for editing it. I didn’t really know how

Comment: [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) might be help you in future.

Comment: Hint: Note that $$f'(\sqrt{1-x^2})=-\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}f'(x).$$ Use this to find $f'$ and then integrate.

Comment: Thanks again 

Comment: When u say f’((1-x^2)^1/2) are u referring to the derivative with respect to x or to (1-x^2)^1/2

Comment: @Bumblebee  Can you add more detail? I don't see how this helps.

Comment: @DavidOkogbenin with respect to $x$

Comment: @Soheil but shouldn’t the left hand side be with respect to (1-x^2)^1/2.

Comment: And how does it even help either way

Comment: @DavidOkogbenin I dont know I am confused

Comment: @Bumblebee Can you show the steps to get that? I don't think it's true.

Answer (score 0):

$$f'(x)=\frac{f(\sqrt{1-x^2})  -  f(x)}x$$
$f(x)=g(x^2)$

$f'(x)=2xg'(x^2)$
$$2xg'(x^2)=\frac{g(1-x^2)  -  g(x^2)}{x}$$
$$2x^2g'(x^2)=g(1-x^2)  -  g(x^2)$$
$x^2=s$
$$2sg'(s)=g(1-s)  -  g(s)$$
$Dg(s)=g'(s)$

$Ag(s)=g(1-s)$
$$(2sD-A+1)g=0$$

[Operator Analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1341495/exponential-of-powers-of-the-derivative-operator/1495596)

$$\left(2sD-\exp\left(\pi isD\right)\exp(D)+1\right)g=0$$
[Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula)

This solves $\ln(\exp(X)\exp(Y))$ which is usually $X+Y$ except when $XY-YX\neq 0$

$\pi isD*D-D*\pi isD=\pi isD^2-\pi i(1+sD)D=\pi isD^2-\pi iD-\pi isD^2=-\pi iD$

$\exp(\pi isD)\exp(D)=\exp(\pi i(s-\frac{1}{2})D)$

$$\left(2sD-\exp\left(\pi i\left(s-\frac{1}{2}\right)D\right)+1\right)g=0$$

There are infinitely many solutions to this but the easiest is $g=0$.

Comment: I’ll have to read up the links you gave as I’m a high school student and I got lost from “Operator Analysis”. What I do know though is that g=k satisfies the equation where k is any real number. Are u saying there are still infinite solutions other than g=k

Comment: Yep. Although why is a bit complicated. It partially has to do with how f(x+1)=f(x) has infinitely many solutions.

Comment: f(x) for f(x+1)=f(x) is a periodic function of a periodicity( don’t know if that’s the word) of 1 right? So something like f(x) = sin(2pix) or f(x)=k. How does this relate to my question?
If it’s still too complex then it’s okay. I’ve found out what I wanted to. But I’d still like to get it though.